# Geometric transform sequences in Java

Tags: java, graphics, affinetransform

Let's say I have a shape and I want to perform a sequence of transformations on it. e.g., `{rotate(1), translate(2), translate(3), rotate(4), translate(5)}`.

To perform the operation, you'd insert them into the AffineTransform "transform" in reverse order:

transform.translate(5)

transform.rotate(4)

etc...

Let's say that there is a common sequence of transformations that I want to store in an AffineTransform object and add as part of my overall sequence of transformations. I'm not sure whether I should use the `concatenate()` method or the `preconcatenate()` method and in what order I should call it. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Why don't you try calling the two methods in both orders? If you are concatenating 2 transforms, there's only 4 permutations to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is quite clear. For example, the documentation for `rotate()` states:

> Concatenates this transform with a rotation transformation

Therefore, you have to `.concatenate()`.

Assume that your transform consists of the partial transforms `M1` thru `M4`:

```
T = M1 * M2 * M3 * M4
```

And assume that the partial transforms correspond to:

```
T.setToIdentity() 
 .rotate(a)     //M1
 .translate(b)  //M2
 .rotate(c)     //M3
 .translate(d)  //M4
```

(just meant as an illustration; the actual syntax is not correct)

Now, if your common transform is `M2 * M3`, you could do:

```
common.setToIdentity()
      .translate(b) //M2
      .rotate(c)    //M3
```

And then:

```
T.setToIdentity() 
 .rotate(a)           //M1
 .concatenate(common) //M2 * M3
 .translate(d)        //M4
```

Note: I haven't checked if *concatenation* actually means multiplication to the right. But even if it means multiplication to the left, the above procedure would not change.